# Group multiple rows into one row having one similar value

Tags: mysql

I have 3 rows in my mysql table, for example

```
company name, tracking type, revenue (columns)
company x, yearly, $100000
company x, monthly, $20000
company x, budget, $30000
```

I need to show company name, yearly, monthly, budget values as a single record, like

```
company x, $100000, $20000, $30000
```

Here I need to group them with company name

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP BY` & `CASE`

```
SELECT company name
 , SUM( CASE tracking type WHEN yearly THEN revenue ELSE 0 END)AS yearly
, SUM( CASE tracking type WHEN monthly THEN revenue ELSE 0 END)AS monthly
, SUM( CASE tracking type WHEN budget THEN revenue ELSE 0 END)AS budget
GROUP BY company name
```